# Asp.net and C# Math Operation from sql to display image

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good day,

I am new here and new to asp.net; I've been working on a project and at the same time learning asp.net for almost 2 months now.

To make the story short,

I have multiple pages, so I will name it from page1 to pageN for us to keep track easily. (N is the total number of pages)

On page1.aspx I have a floorplan of my company as the page background. and set each department as an imagebutton (so that it can redirect to the department's page onclick)

On the other hand I have page2.aspx. Page2.aspx is a report form, where incident report is being made and submitted from this page to page3.aspx

Page3.aspx holds the database of incident reports for each department.

Now, what I wanted to happen are;

1. page1.aspx checks the database from page3.aspx.
2. page1.aspx compares the DateTime.Now from datetime on a row from database used in page3.aspx
3. If DateTime.Now is 4 hours greater than the datetime on a row from database. Then;
4. Imagebutton.ImageUrl = "~/Red.gif"; on page1.aspx

I hope you understand what I wanted to happen.

Please help me with the code that I need to use on page1.aspx.cs to;

1. Read time from database
2. Compare time from database against current time
3. Change imagebutton4.imagurl upon success of if else statement.

Thank you so much.

Comment: improved list formatting

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please share some of the code you already tried / created?